# Selecting a part of a string according to a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

First of all I'm sorry about the title, I didn't know how to formulate what I want to do.

Here is a part of the string I want to analyze :

```
Microsoft Application Error Reporting<br><br />Microsoft Application Error Reporting<br><br />Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010<br><br />Microsoft Office OneNote MUI (English) 2010<br><br />
```

And here is the website where I display the string :
[Website](http://www.noelshack.com/2012-23-1338808905-SiteWebV3.png)

Now what I'd like to do : When I click a checkbox, I'd like to take the part of the string associated to the checkbox' line and put it in another string.
For example, if I select the 9th checkbox, I'd like to put `Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2007` in a new string.

I've made a piece of code going to the specified line, but I don't know how to use it now...

```
int i=0; 
        do
        {
            int j = 0;
            while ((j = (InstalledSoftwares.Text).IndexOf("<br><br />", j)) != -1)
            {
                j += "<br><br />".Length;
                i++;
            }
        } while (i <= Convert.ToInt16(TextBoxTest.Text));
```

`InstalledSoftwares.Text` is the string I want to analyze. 
`TextBoxTest` contains the number of the checkbox.

I searched a lot to find an answer to my problem but didn't find anything.. Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Use ASP.NET controls(in this case a [`CheckBoxList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx), then you could use it's [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) property) instead of home-made html strings.

Comment: Maybe you can split the string on the basis of `br` tags and then get it

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm sorry but how can I do that ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta This is what I tried to do, but I can't figure out how I can.. :/

Comment: using `.Split(new []{"<br>< br/>"}, ...`

Comment: @V4Vendetta Oh, I didn't know about this method, I'm feeling so dumb right know. Thanks ! So if I split my string, I'm going to have a char array with all the softwares ? And to select the desired software, can I call it like "InstalledSoftwares[9]" if I want the 9th ? Thanks !

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza well not really cause its zero indexed so should be `[8]` :) check it out

Comment: @V4Vendetta Oops, yep you're right ! Thanks a lot, I'm trying to do like you said. I'd like to mark your comment as answer but I can't since it's a comment. Thanks again !

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza I have added it as answer, you may choose to accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the Split option to split the text and then pick the relevent text from the array with relation to the checkbox checked

```
InstalledSoftwares.Text.Split(new []{"<br>< br/>"}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now you can use the index `8` to get the relevant text for checkbox 9 (since array is zero indexed)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again, it will help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx)

```
Split Pattern = @"\s*<br>\s*<br\s*/>\s*"
```

Product Name = CheckBox Index - 1

---

```
String[] Products = Regex.Split(XML, Pattern);
String Product = Products[ CheckBoxIndex - 1 ];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try V4Vendetta's solution and if it doesn't work I'll try yours. :)